# React Native Vector icon installation

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble in installing react native vector icon
after installing
I followed with gradle option
just add the lines in android/app/build.gradle like this in the end of the file like following:
[image]

and getting this error after react-native run-android
[image]

Comment: After installing vector-icons are did run `react-native link` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide in their repo is outdated. After you do the `npm install` you need to run `react-native link`.

See the [doc section](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#automatic-linking)